# what is difference between scope and namespace in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, namespaces, global, local

*hi everyone* . actually I'm newly learning Javascript . I read about scopes in javascript . then I read somewhere about namespace in Js and i was wondered if namespace is exactly the same as scope , so i searched but the results were just explained for python and I don't know if they are the same in js or not  .

> would someone explain the difference between scope and namespace in js ?

**my definition of scope** : scope is a concept in programming language that helps us to prevent variable pollution . it means we control the accessibility to the variables and function in our code . js is a function scope language it means new scopes will create if we create new function . we can declare block scope instead of function scope variable and function with the help of new keywords **let** , **const**

Comment: There is nothing officially called "namespace" in JavaScript. There *is* an official concept called "scope". So, I guess the difference is that one exists, the other doesn't.

Comment: @VLAZ - [Module Namespace Exotic Objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, I stand corrected. But I feel OP isn't talking about module namespace exotic objects specifically.

Comment: _"...I read somewhere about namespace in Js"_ - where did you read it? Can you share the link?

Comment: @VLAZ - Agreed. :-) Though they were probably reading something about old-style modules or similar... Would be good if the OP clarified what they were reading.

Comment: A short and simple [description](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-namespace/)

Comment: @KooiInc that's just an object. Some resources wrongly call objects "namespaces" by borrowing terminology from elsewhere. But objects are objects.

Answer (score 4):

**"Namespace"** is only used in the JavaScript specification in relation to the [module namespace exotic object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects), which is an object created (or reused) when you do an `import *` from a module. It contains properties for all of the module's named exports (and a property called `default` if it has a default export).

Before JavaScript had official modules, "namespace" wasn't used in the definition of JavaScript at all. It was used *informally* to refer to an object that was created by a unit of code (loosely, a "module") with properties for the "exports" of that module, like this:

```
// ES5 code - one style of the "revealing module pattern"
var MyLib = (function() {
    function internalFunction() {
        // ...
    }

    return {
        exportedFunction: function() {
            // ...
        }
    };
})();
```

There, `MyLib` was sometimes called a "namespace," but that was purely informal. It's just an object.

**"Scope"** is a region of program source code that defines a container for variables and related things. (Sometimes it's used to refer to the resulting "objects" defined by the specification, but they're more properly called lexical [environment records](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-environment-records).) For example, this source code has two explicit scopes:

```
function example(someParam) {
    if (someParam === "some value") {
        console.log("something");
    }
}
```

The scopes are:

- Function scope within the `{}` defining the function body.
- Block scope within the `{}` defining the block on the `if`.

(There's also the implicit scope around the function, which depends on where this source code appears — sometimes called the "ambient scope.")

At runtime, when `example` is called, the specification describes creating an environment record for the function scope and later creating an environment record for the block scope. (That's just specification language; a JavaScript engine doesn't have to do it literally.) Sometimes, a scope can have two environment records defined for it (global scope is like that) but usually it's one-for-one.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer T.J. Crowder . you know , I'm very beginner in JS and your i found some concept in your explanation that I haven't read about them . so i think its better to finish the entire course and then again read yours .

Comment: @mahdizarepoor - Fair enough and I hope your learning goes well! BTW, your definition of "scope" isn't bad at all. It's not *just* isolating variables, but what you have is really not a bad starting point for understanding it.